# Using \r in Java for Count Down Timer

Tags: java, counter, countdown, overwrite, println

how to use \r in Java properly for Count Down Timer?
i want to count down from 20 to 0 and print this, i want to update this instead of writing in new line so i used \r . it works, but when it comes to 10, then after this, instead of writing 9 it writes 90, 80 and so on... plz update my code to solve problem. thanks
here is my code

```
int timer1=20;
int timer2=0;
String timer3="\r";
while(timer1>timer2){
try {Thread.sleep(1000);} catch (InterruptedException e) {e.printStackTrace();}  
System.out.print(timer3+timer1);   
System.out.flush(); 
timer1--;}
```

Comment: This is because the second character `0` remains there. use `09`, `08` etc

Comment: Or just print an additional space character at the end.

Comment: @Kayaman it works! using spaces at end. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your variable names ae confusing to say the least. The problem you are having is that the \r is taking you to the start of the line and you are not overwriting the previous output so that when you write out the number 9 you are still left with the 0 from 10.

Change this line:

```
   System.out.print(timer3+timer1);
```

to:

```
   System.out.print(timer3+timer1+ " ");
```

and this should fix things.